# Adapter Pattern in ruby: Accessing Your Instance Variables

Tags: ruby

I am studying the [adapter pattern](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-and-testing-the-adapter-design-pattern/) implementation in ruby.  I want to access an instance variable within the adapter module definition.  Take a look at the following code:

```
module Adapter
  module Dog
    def self.speak
      # I want to access the #name instance variable from my Animal instance
      puts "#{name} says: woof!"
    end
  end

  module Cat
    def self.speak
      # I want to access the #name instance variable from my Animal instance
      puts "#{name} says: meow!"
    end
  end
end

class Animal
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def speak
    self.adapter.speak
  end

  def adapter
    return @adapter if @adapter
    self.adapter = :dog
    @adapter
  end

  def adapter=(adapter)
    @adapter = Adapter.const_get(adapter.to_s.capitalize)
  end
end
```

To test it out I did the following:

```
animal = Animal.new("catdog")
animal.adapter = :cat
animal.speak
```

I want it to return the following:

```
catdog says: meow!
```

Instead it says:

```
Adapter::Cat says: meow!
```

Any tips on how I can get access to the `Animal#name` instance method from the adapter module?  I think the issue is that my adapter methods are class-level methods.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want `@adapter ||= :dog` as that's often more concise, but don't forget that returning `:dog.speak` isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your Module as a mixin and provide a way to keep track of which module is active, the methods don't seem to be overwritten by reincluding or reextending so I took the extend and remove methods I found [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/164431).

```
module Adapter
  module Dog
    def speak
      puts "#{name} says: woof!"
    end
  end

  module Cat
    def speak
      puts "#{name} says: meow!"
    end
  end

  def extend mod
    @ancestors ||= {}
    return if @ancestors[mod]
    mod_clone = mod.clone
    @ancestors[mod] = mod_clone
    super mod_clone
  end

  def remove mod
    mod_clone = @ancestors[mod]
    mod_clone.instance_methods.each {|m| mod_clone.module_eval {remove_method m } }
    @ancestors[mod] = nil
  end
end

class Animal
  include Adapter
  attr_accessor :name, :adapter

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @adapter = Adapter::Dog
    extend Adapter::Dog
  end

  def adapter=(adapter)
    remove @adapter
    extend Adapter::const_get(adapter.capitalize)
    @adapter = Adapter.const_get(adapter.capitalize)
  end
end

animal = Animal.new("catdog")
animal.speak # catdog says: woof!
animal.adapter = :cat
animal.speak # catdog says: meow!
animal.adapter = :dog
animal.speak # catdog says: woof!
```

Comment: thanks Peter!  This almost works.  However: at the very bottom try changing it back to the dog and then calling `animal.speak`.  It still is responding the cat way, even though we want it to change back to the dog way.

Comment: let me know if you have any suggestions.  Both your answer and tadman's answer are really close.  However they both only allow the adapter (:cat, :dog) to be toggled once.  They both do not let you toggle back to the former one (ex: toggling the adapter back to :dog).

Comment: That was a hard one, needed a dedicated extend and remove method, got it from https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/164431, now it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

This is because `name` inside of the `module` context refers to something entirely different than the `name` you're expecting. The `Animal` class and the `Cat` module do not share data, they have no relationship. Coincidentally you're calling [`Module#name`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-name) which happens to return `Adapter::Cat` as that's the name of the module.

In order to get around this you need to do one of two things. Either make your `module` a mix-in (remove `self`, then `include` it as necessary) or share the necessary data by passing it in as an argument to `speak`.

The first method looks like this:

```
module Adapter
  module Dog
    def self.speak(name)
      puts "#{name} says: woof!"
    end
  end
end

class Animal
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_reader :adapter

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name

    self.adapter = :dog
  end

  def speak
    self.adapter.speak(@name)
  end

  def adapter=(adapter)
    @adapter = Adapter.const_get(adapter.to_s.capitalize)
  end
end
```

That doesn't seem as simple as it could be as they basically live in two different worlds. A more Ruby-esque way is this:

```
module Adapter
  module Dog
    def speak
      puts "#{name} says: woof!"
    end
  end
end

class Animal
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_reader :adapter

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name

    self.adapter = :dog
  end

  def adapter=(adapter)
    @adapter = Adapter.const_get(adapter.to_s.capitalize)

    extend(@adapter)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I tried out your second suggested answer.  Unfortunately changing the adapter does not change the answer.  Example: it starts by using the Dog's version of `speak`.  I then do `animal.adapter = :cat`.  But when I do `animal.speak` it still responds with the Dog version. It seems like `extend(@adapter)` will not override the Dog's `speak` with the Cat's `speak`.

Comment: hadn't seen tadman's answer otherwise I would have skipped this, but my solution works, I presume because of the order in adapter=

Comment: @Neil Be sure that your module declares the method `speak` and not `self.speak`. If you forget that the method won't be mixed in properly. I tested this code and it worked for me, but I omitted the Cat part for brevity's sake.

Comment: hmm, still having some trouble.  I posted another question about the exact result I am getting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863613/overriding-module-behavior-with-another-module