# Overriding Module Mixin Behavior by Mixing in another Module

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to toggle back and forth how an instance responds to a message.  I want to do that by mixing in a module, and then later mixing in another module to override that behavior.

Example:

```
module Dog
  def speak
    puts "woof woof"
  end
end

module Cat
  def speak
    puts "meow"
  end
end

class Animal
end
```

Now I want to toggle, back and forth, how an instance of `Animal` responds to the `speak` message:

```
animal = Animal.new

animal.extend(Cat)
animal.speak

animal.extend(Dog)
animal.speak

animal.extend(Cat)
animal.speak

animal.extend(Dog)
animal.speak

animal.extend(Cat)
animal.speak
```

I would expect this code to output the following:

```
meow
woof woof
meow
woof woof
meow
```

Instead it outputs like this:

```
meow
woof woof
woof woof
woof woof
woof woof
```

Any tips on how I can get this to work as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I adapted the answer at your other question at [Adapter Pattern in ruby: Accessing Your Instance Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861791/adapter-pattern-in-ruby-accessing-your-instance-variables/41863318#41863318)

```
module Dog
  def speak
    puts "woof woof"
  end
end

module Cat
  def speak
    puts "meow"
  end
end

module Module_manager
  attr_accessor :name
  def extend mod
    @ancestors ||= {}
    return if @ancestors[mod]
    remove @name if @name
    @name = mod
    mod_clone = mod.clone
    @ancestors[mod] = mod_clone
    super mod_clone
  end

  def remove mod
    mod_clone = @ancestors[mod]
    mod_clone.instance_methods.each {|m| mod_clone.module_eval {remove_method m } }
    @ancestors[mod] = nil
  end
end

class Animal
  include Module_manager
end

animal = Animal.new

animal.extend(Cat)
animal.speak # meow

animal.extend(Dog)
animal.speak # woof woof

animal.extend(Cat)
animal.speak # meow

animal.extend(Dog)
animal.speak # woof woof

animal.extend(Cat)
animal.speak # meow
```

Comment: I've never seen the need for a `unextend` (`retract`?) method but this is a good implementation of that. Only quibble is that should be `ModuleManager` to follow Ruby naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the following answers your question, but it's a simpler way to achieve the same behaviour.

```
class Animal
  include Dog
  alias :dog_speak :speak
  include Cat
  alias :cat_speak :speak
  private :dog_speak, :cat_speak

  def initialize
    @speak_to_me = [:cat_speak, :dog_speak].cycle
  end  

  def speak
    send @speak_to_me.next
  end
end

animal = Animal.new
  #=> #<Animal:0x007fe3a222b0e0 @speak_to_me=#<Enumerator:
  #     [:cat_speak, :dog_speak]:cycle>> 

animal.speak #-> meow
animal.speak #-> woof woof
animal.speak #-> meow
animal.speak #-> woof woof
```

Comment: OP wanted to experiment with the adapter pattern in Ruby

Comment: You're answer does achieve the same behavior for the exact code sample I provided, so it is a solid answer.  However your answer limits an `animal` to responding in the exact order of how a `cat` speaks and then how a `dog` speaks.  Example: pretend there were 5 different ways an animal can `speak`.  Instead of the user just cycling through those different ways of speaking, I want to give the client the ability to pick and choose which way it speaks.  Hopefully that makes sense.  Again though: I did not specify this in the original question so technically your answer is sufficient.

Comment: Neil, that was my suspicion.